# How do I choose what and how many frames I want to process?

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am working on object detection but the real time detection is very slow. So to avoid processing each and every frames I just want to take first 5 frames from each 30 frames and use that 5 frames for processing a particular function and later on take 3 frames for my object detection model. I am new to OpenCV so please let me know how can I achieve this?

Comment: you have to implement your own data flow. E.g. you could use 2 threads, one fills a buffer with all the images and the second one chooses, processes and drops frames according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention real-time, I'll assume you're capturing from a camera. In that case you can read the frame such that the intermittent frames get dumped as in the example below. Notice that this keeps up with real-time, even with the introduced delay. So in this scenario you don't have to select which frames are processed, you just process a single frame and come back to the video source and you get the latest frame.

If you need to handle every frame then consider the @Micka comment to your question. [Here is a good post](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/06/faster-video-file-fps-with-cv2-videocapture-and-opencv/) on creating an efficient frame queue.

```
import cv2
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Get frame: notice that you get the most recent frame
    # The frames you miss get dumped
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # peform some slow operation
    time.sleep(1)

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Sorry but I am noob in computer vision, so how do I take 5 frames out of 30 frames at start for executing function  a and for function b and c, I'll take 3 frames per second. Could you make your code specifically to meet this requirement?

Comment: The approach above avoids having to skip and grab specific frames, but if you must, then cap.read() into a queue data structure, then get your frames from that. The queue will store every frame so if you have slow processing operations, you won't miss any frames (but you won't be real-time).